# Making a near empty flash drive easy to compress

Tags: ssd, usb-flash-drive, flash

I have a flash drive, which is ten-percent full, but has been used extensively.  (i.e. a large minority of blocks will contain random noise.)

In order to make a small, compressed image of this drive (if it were an HDD) I would `dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/zeros.tmp bs=16M; rm /tmp/zeros.tmp`.  This fills all unused blocks with zeros, so that an image of the drive compresses well.

With a flash drive, would there be any advantage in writing `0xFF`s to unused blocks, instead of zeros?  i.e. is the flash drive clever enough to not rewrite a page that already contains `0xFF`s?

Comment: Why fill the disk with 0xff?

Comment: When NAND flash (used in most devices) is erased, it's contents will be all 1's, hence 0xff. It's a good question actually.